# Calendar Inline Framework7-vue bug in popup

Tags: vue.js, html-framework-7

I have the following problem when creating an inline calendar in a popup in Framework7, in the first view it appears perfect, but when you close the modal and return to the home page and then return to the internal page and open the inline calendar again it does not appear.

I am creating a calendar inside a component called calendar that is imported by a modal-date.

```
mounted() {
  const self = this;
  const app = self.$f7;
  var $$ = Dom7;
  var selected;
  var monthNames = [
  "Janeiro",
  "Fevereiro",
  "Março",
  "Abril",
  "Maio",
  "Junho",
  "Julho",
  "Agosto",
  "Setembro",
  "Outubro",
  "Novembro",
  "Dezembro",
];
var calendarInline = app.calendar.create({
  containerEl: "#demo-calendar-inline-container",
  value: [new Date()],
  minDate: new Date(),
  renderToolbar: function () {
    return (
      '<div class="toolbar calendar-custom-toolbar no-shadow">' +
      '<div class="toolbar-inner">' +
      '<div class="left">' +
      '<a href="#" class="link icon-only"><i class="icon icon-back ' +
      (app.theme === "md" ? "color-black" : "") +
      '"></i></a>' +
      "</div>" +
      '<div class="center"></div>' +
      '<div class="right">' +
      '<a href="#" class="link icon-only"><i class="icon icon-forward ' +
      (app.theme === "md" ? "color-black" : "") +
      '"></i></a>' +
      "</div>" +
      "</div>" +
      "</div>"
    );
  },
  on: {
    init: function (c) {
      $$(".calendar-custom-toolbar .center").text(
        monthNames[c.currentMonth] + ", " + c.currentYear
      );
      $$(".calendar-custom-toolbar .left .link").on("click", function () {
        calendarInline.prevMonth();
      });
      $$(".calendar-custom-toolbar .right .link").on("click", function () {
        calendarInline.nextMonth();
      });
      $$(".calendar-day-today").removeClass(
        "calendar-day-selected calendar-day-disabled"
      );
    },
    monthYearChangeStart: function (c) {
      $$(".calendar-custom-toolbar .center").text(
        monthNames[c.currentMonth] + ", " + c.currentYear
      );
    },
    dayClick: function (calendar, dayEl, year, month, day) {
      // SET IS LOADING
      self.$store.commit('SET_IS_LOADING', true);
      selected = {
        day: day,
        month: month,
        year: year,
      };
      var currentDay = $$(".calendar-day-today"); //current day
      currentDay.removeClass("calendar-day-disabled");

      dateSelected(selected);
    },
  },
});
function dateSelected(selected) {
  self.selected(selected);
}
}
```

Comment: Hi @kelvin natanael, can you add some code to you example?

Comment: @Dr.MantisTobbogan I updated the post with the code.